# hibernate.cfg.xml not being picked up

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, maven

I have created a maven web project. The stack is Spring + hibernate + jersey.

I have this hibernate.cfg.xml under src/main/resources/ path. When I try to deploy it an tomcat I get this stacktrace,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'WorkspacesDBSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:863)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 34 more
```

When i checked the DialectFactory.java:57, i found the code,

```
public static Dialect determineDialect(String databaseName, int databaseMajorVersion) {
    if ( databaseName == null ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set" );
    }
```

So the actual issue was that the, hibernate.cfg.xml was not being loaded. So I removed the file and tried the deployment. I again got the same stacktrace.

My ApplicationContext.xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.work.autogen, org.work.db.api, org.work.services, org.work.routes">
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="log4jInitializer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="WorkspacesDBSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <!-- <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Appraisal.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Managers.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>EmployeeSecretUuid.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Work.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Company.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">Workspacedb</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My Hibernate.cfg.xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory><!-- name="sessionFactory"> --> 
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Workspacedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">workadmin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="Appraisal.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Managers.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="EmployeeSecretUuid.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Work.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Company.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

How I do make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: My intention is that the hibernate.cfg.xml to be picked up automatically. I dont want to call it explicitly in a programming way.

Comment: what is the location of hibernate.cfg.xml file in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the logs, it is the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` that is trying to configure `Hibernate`.

Also in your Spring configuration file you are not mentioning anywhere that you have a separate Hibernate configuration file.

So in this code:

```
<bean id="WorkspacesDBSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">Workspacedb</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

you are just setting the hibernate properties for `dialect` and `hibernate.default_schema`.

To fix the issue change the property `dialect` to `hibernate.dialect`.

Now if you still want to use the Hibernate configuration file then you need to set the [configLocation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setConfigLocation-org.springframework.core.io.Resource-) property in your spring configuration file.

Here is an example on how to use the configLocation property:

```
<bean id="WorkspacesDBSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
```

You can see detailed explanation in this post: 
[applicationContext.xml with datasource or hibernate.cfg.xml. Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634475/applicationcontext-xml-with-datasource-or-hibernate-cfg-xml-difference)

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate.cfg.xml must be in CLASSPATH to pick up automatically. Try to put /src/main/java.
Because Hibernate finds firstly  in CLASSPATH default(/src/main/java)

Comment: it is a maven project as shown in tags of this question, so keeping it in `src/main/resources` is the correct way of placing any configuration files in maven. Once the project is build, then the configuration file will be placed in the root of the classpath.

Comment: But how it´s maven´s configuration, when he runs maven?

Comment: I did not understand your question, can you please elaborate?

Comment: My question is: when he runs maven, how the app is packing? Because putting hibernate.cfg.xml in src/main/resources is not guaranteed that hibernate will find it to load it.

Comment: Please check maven docs on how maven works. For your question, check this post --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258594/hibernate-exception-hibernate-cfg-xml-not-found

Comment: Ok I got it. I thought he tried to deploy the app directly by eclipse.